# What is the definition of a scalar parameter?

Tags: parameterization

I'm having trouble understanding what explicity is a scalar parameter. I understand what a location parameter and scale parameter represent but what exactly is the definition of a scalar parameter? From the context of the problem I'm working with I get the sense that a scalar parameter is defined as theta that is approximately normally distributed with hyperparameters mu & sigma. But what does theta then actually represent and why is it called a scalar parameter?

Thanks

Comment: I have not seen the phrase "scalar parameter" but I guess, like in mathematics, scalar is just number and different from a vector.

Comment: When someone says a number is scalar, it typically means it is not a higher-dimension vector or matrix. I'm assuming the text you read this from is just trying to say that the theta variable is a scalar (a single value) rather than a vector or matrix.

Comment: I appreciate the comments, I think I was able to figure it out. It's simply a probability distribution of the parameter  θ  (e.g.  μ  and  σ  in the case of a normal distribution). The problem I'm working on is a for a normal approximation of the posterior theta (from Gelman BDA) so it makes contextual sense. I hadn't encountered the term before and I was unable to find an explicit defintion for it.